# Call a class declared inside another class in python

Tags: python

I'm learnig python. I want to know how can I use a class inside another class to do something like that:

```
class wardrove:
    class drawer1:
        def __init__(self):
            self.sokcs='red'
    class drawer2:
        def __init__(self):
            self.hats='black'
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.drawer1()
        self.drawer2()
        self.shirts='white'
        
wardrove_lane=[]
for i in range(0,2):
    wardrove_lane.append(wardrove())


wardrove_lane[1].drawer1.sokcs='green'
wardrove_lane[0].drawer1.sokcs='blue'

print(wardrove_lane[1].drawer1.sokcs)
print(wardrove_lane[0].drawer1.sokcs)
```

In this example I get:

> blue
>
> blue

but I expect:

> green
>
> blue

Thanks

Comment: It would be simpler to define those classes outside the `wardrove` class.

Comment: `wardrove_lane[1].drawer1`is the same as `wardrove_lane[0].drawer1`.

Comment: And really, you probably don't even need 2 `drawer` classes, just one should be sufficient. In fact, I'd probably write that code without any custom classes: I'd just use a `dict`.

Comment: PM 2Ring, if you have a better answer I will be happy to learn about it. Please take a moment and write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign `self.drawer1()` and `self.drawer2()` to separate instances, such as `self.d1` and `self.d2`:

```
class wardrove:
   def __init__(self):
       self.d1 = self.drawer1()
       self.d2 = self.drawer2()
       self.shirts='white'
   class drawer1:
      def __init__(self):
         self.sokcs='red'
   class drawer2:
      def __init__(self):
         self.hats='black'


wardrove_lane=[]
for i in range(0,2):
   wardrove_lane.append(wardrove())


wardrove_lane[1].d1.sokcs='green'
wardrove_lane[0].d2.sokcs='blue'
print(wardrove_lane[1].d1.sokcs)
print(wardrove_lane[0].d2.sokcs)
```

Output:

```
green
blue
```

However, if you do want to access the attributes by class instance, than you can slightly restructure your code using the `classmethod` wrapper:

```
class wardrove:
   def __init__(self):
       self.d1 = self.drawer1()
       self.d2 = self.drawer2()
       self.shirts='white'
   class drawer1:
      sokcs='red'
      @classmethod
      def update(cls, value):
          cls.sokcs = value
   class drawer2:
      hats='black'
      @classmethod
      def update(cls, value):
         cls.hats = value

wardrove_lane=[]
for i in range(0,2):
   wardrove_lane.append(wardrove())

wardrove_lane[1].drawer1.update('green')
wardrove_lane[0].drawer2.update('blue')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need instantiate the constructor in two new variables, in this way:

```
class wardrove:
   class drawer1:
       def __init__(self):
           self.sokcs='red'
   class drawer2:
       def __init__(self):
           self.hats='black'

   def __init__(self):
       self.d1 = self.drawer1()
       self.d2 = self.drawer2()
       self.shirts='white'

wardrove_lane=[]
for i in range(0,2):
    wardrove_lane.append(wardrove())


wardrove_lane[1].d1.sokcs='green'
wardrove_lane[0].d1.sokcs='blue'

print(wardrove_lane[1].d1.sokcs)
print(wardrove_lane[0].d1.sokcs)
```